# Como ler o resultado de um Array de JSON usando Ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic2, ionic3

Estou fazendo um GET para login, porem preciso pegar o ID do usuário para a sessão também:

```
submit(){
    var link = 'http://localhost:1337/usuario?email='+ this.usuario.email  + '&senha='+ this.usuario.senha;
    var data = JSON.stringify({ email: this.usuario.email, senha: this.usuario.senha});

      this.http.get(link)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data.response = data._body;
       if(this.data.response != "[]"){
         console.log(this.data.response);

        // tinha que pegar o ID do usuário.... :/
         sessionStorage.setItem("usuarioEmail", this.usuario.email);
         sessionStorage.setItem("flagLogado", "sim");
         this.navCtrl.setRoot(WellFitPage, {}, {animate: true, direction: "forward"});
        }else{
          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Usuário Não encontrado!',
            subTitle: 'Verifique se digitou seu e-mail e senha corretamente.',
            buttons: ['OK']
          });
          alert.present();
       }
    })
  }
```

Meu:

```
console.log(this.data.response);
```

Imprime este resultado no Console:

```
[
  {
    "nome": "Ramos",
    "email": "ramos@email.com.br",
    "celular": "34996320391",
    "telefone": null,
    "data_nascimento": null,
    "altura": null,
    "peso": null,
    "gordura": null,
    "vo2": null,
    "senha": "teste",
    "cmkey": null,
    "id": 4,
    "createdAt": "2018-03-28T18:08:22.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-03-28T18:08:22.000Z"
  }
]
```

Como pegar o id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua variável local `this.data.response` é um *array*, portanto é necessário acessar sua primeira posição e em seguida usar *dot notation* para acessar a propriedade desejada.

```js
const response = [
  {
    "nome": "Ramos",
    "email": "ramos@email.com.br",
    "celular": "34996320391",
    "telefone": null,
    "data_nascimento": null,
    "altura": null,
    "peso": null,
    "gordura": null,
    "vo2": null,
    "senha": "teste",
    "cmkey": null,
    "id": 4,
    "createdAt": "2018-03-28T18:08:22.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-03-28T18:08:22.000Z"
  }
];

console.log(response[0].id);
```

Comment: estou tentando console.log('O ID do usuário é: '+ this.data.response[0].id); mas dá que é undefined

Comment: @Ramos e se você fizer `http.get(link).map(response => response.json()).subscribe(data => { this.data.response = data; console.log(this.data.response[0.id]); });`?

Comment: O problema era que era uma grande string, que resolvi fazendo um JSON.parse(this.data.response); e aplicando a sua resposta. E deu certo. Obrigado @mercador. :)